Should the expected value of a test be calculated?
We have the following method.
public int Factorial(int number)
{
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
    {
        result *= i;
    }
    return result;
}

And we have two tests of this method.
[Fact]
void FactorialTest1()
{
    const int number = 4;

    int expectedResult = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
    {
        expectedResult *= i;
    }

    var actualResult = Factorial(number);

    Assert.Equal(expectedResult, actualResult);
}

[Fact]
void FactorialTest2()
{
    const int number = 4;
    const int expectedResult = 24;

    var actualResult = Factorial(number);

    Assert.Equal(expectedResult, actualResult);
}

Which of these tests is more correct?
The first test completely duplicates the code of the Factorial method. It seems wrong to me

The latter one. If you're just replicating your algorithm, you'll be replicating any bugs in your assumptions as well. The first one isn't actually testing anything.
